# How can i execute a stored procedure inside another stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m working with SQLServer and I have two storedprocedures

The first one:

```
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @FECHAFIN AS datetime;

SET @FECHAFIN = @FECHAINICIO + '23:59:59.999'

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT
  HC.idCorrida AS Referencia,
  T.part AS Parte,
  T.idTrabajo AS Trabajo,
  HC.cantidadFabricado AS Piezas,
  HC.cantidadRechazado AS Rechazo,
  CONVERT(varchar(8), HC.tiempoProduccion) AS TiempoDeProduccion,
  CONVERT(varchar(8), HC.tiempoMuerto) AS TiempoMuerto,
  HC.fechaInicio AS Fecha,
  U.nombreUsuario AS Usuario,
  MA.nombre AS NombreMaquina,
  TR.nombre AS NombreTripulacion,
  TXM.idTurno AS Turno,

FROM [Produccion].[HistorialCorridas] AS HC
INNER JOIN [Produccion].[Trabajos] AS T
  ON HC.idTrabajo = T.idTrabajo
INNER JOIN [Administracion].[Usuarios] AS U
  ON U.idUsuario = HC.idUsuario AND U.idTripulacion = @IDTRIPULACION
INNER JOIN [Administracion].[Tripulaciones] AS TR
  ON U.idTripulacion = TR.idTripulacion
WHERE HC.idTurnoXMaquina = @IDTURNOXMAQUINA
  AND HC.fechaInicio >= @FECHAINICIO AND HC.fechaInicio <= @FECHAFIN
GROUP BY HC.idCorrida, T.part, T.idTrabajo, HC.cantidadFabricado, HC.cantidadRechazado,
  HC.tiempoProduccion, HC.tiempoMuerto, HC.fechaInicio, U.nombreUsuario, MA.nombre, TR.nombre, TXM.idTurno
END
```

The second one:

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON          
SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DATEADD(SECOND,SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '00:00:00', TiempoMuerto)),0),114) AS TotalTiempoMuerto,     
  P.etiqueta AS TipoParo
FROM [Produccion].[TiemposMuertos]
INNER JOIN [Administracion].[ParosXMaquina] AS PM
  ON PM.id = idParoXMaquina
INNER JOIN [Administracion].[Paros] AS P
  ON P.idParo = PM.idParo
WHERE idCorrida = @IDCORRIDA
GROUP BY P.etiqueta
END
```

The second one receives as a parameter a field called `Referencia` from the first stored procedure. What I want to do, is execute the second stored procedure from the first one, passing that parameter.

How could I achieve this? Is it possible to get the result in just one query?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Learn to use views.

Answer (score 1):

To call a `PROCEDURE` from another `PROCEDURE` that returns a value as output, you must use the `out` keyword for the output, which may be a table or other data type.

The following two procedures are defined.

*In test1 procedure, the return parameter is specified with out.*

*In the second procedure, the first procedure is called as follows:*

```
DECLARE @result int
EXEC test1 @result OUTPUT
```

---

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test1
(@outID int output)
AS
BEGIN
SET @outID = (select top 1 ID from table1)
END




CREATE PROCEDURE test2
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @result int
      EXEC test1 @result OUTPUT
      SELECT ID from table2 where ID = @result
    END;
END
GO

EXEC test2
```